# Best way to calculate nth degree connections on a graph

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, graph-databases, arangodb, spark-graphx

I have a graph database on ArangoDB which have a node depth of around 100 levels and around 205k nodes for some users. For normal uses the AQL used to traverse the graph works well. But there are some scenarios on which the graph traversal is taking too much time, which are:

1. Calculating the maximum depth for some user
2. Calculating weight for a root node which have a node depth around 50+ and child node 200k+. Here weight is calculated by summing the weight of each child node.
3. Fetching all the nodes on a specific level for some node.

The solutions tried by me is as following:

- For #1 and #2, I am calculating the maximum depth and weight in the background and keeping them to a cache to avoid real time processing. Also these are recalculated if there any changes in the graph.
- For #3, I have tried placing the graph on shards which actually worsen the performance ( and it was expected because graph can not utilize sharding benefits)

I need suggestions for the following:

- Is it a good idea to pre-calculate the user ids on each level and placing it to cache for each user?
- Is there a way to split the graph on different shards ( some better way) so that my query can run in parallel to finish the task of fetching the node data early?
- Can the tools like Elastic search or Spark, be helpful to improve the performance of a Graph query?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at graphulo/accumulo

Comment: @ookboy24, it seems this project has stopped updates and also I am not sure it is a wise decision to replace arangodb because it is running on production server. Can you provide some insight if this library can achieve what I am looking for if you have any experience of using graphulo/accumulo